# How do I call REST API from an android app?

Tags: android, rest

I'm new to android and new to programming as well. How do I call a REST api (GET/POST request) from an android app. Please suggest me a good tutorial, or give me an idea to start with.

Comment: Search for `android http library` in most cases they have nice examples

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/

Answer (score 79, accepted):

1. If you want to integrate Retrofit (all steps defined here):

Goto my blog : [retrofit with kotlin](https://blogs.datanapps.com/retrofit-kotlin-jetpack)

2. Please use android-async-http library.

the link below explains everything step by step.

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Here are sample apps:

1. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/calling-restful-services-from-your-android-app/
2. http://blog.strikeiron.com/bid/73189/Integrate-a-REST-API-into-Android-Application-in-less-than-15-minutes

**Create a class :**

```
public class HttpUtils {
  private static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/1/";
 
  private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

  public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
      client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
  }

  public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
      client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
  }
      
  public static void getByUrl(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
      client.get(url, params, responseHandler);
  }

  public static void postByUrl(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
      client.post(url, params, responseHandler);
  }

  private static String getAbsoluteUrl(String relativeUrl) {
      return BASE_URL + relativeUrl;
  }
}
```

**Call Method :**

```
    RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
    rp.add("username", "aaa"); rp.add("password", "aaa@123");
                    
    HttpUtils.post(AppConstant.URL_FEED, rp, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            // If the response is JSONObject instead of expected JSONArray
            Log.d("asd", "---------------- this is response : " + response);
            try {
                JSONObject serverResp = new JSONObject(response.toString());                                                
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                   
        }
            
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray timeline) {
            // Pull out the first event on the public timeline
                    
        }
    });
```

Please grant internet permission in your manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

---

you can add `compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'` for `Header[]` and `compile 'org.json:json:20160212'` for `JSONObject` in build.gradle file if required.

Comment: Thank you. strikeon link seems easy, I'm going to try that

Comment: this tutorial uses http get() method. what if I want to use post()?

Comment: http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/

Comment: and also check my ans. i have update it

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is too difficult for me to understand.

Comment: 1. Copy a jar file from http://loopj.com/android-async-http/  and place in lib folder. 2.Place class HttpUtils in your source folder. 3. Call method where you want to call api.

Comment: I would have suggested [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). I can't think of an easier way for consuming a REST api on Android. Anyway, I'm leaving this here for future users that get here.

Comment: What's AppConstant.URL_FEED? It wasn't found here. Using the latest Android Studio, minSdkVersion 16 and targetSdkVersion 24.

Comment: AppConstant.URL_FEED this is relative url, this is using in my app by constant string. u can use by constant file or direct give API

Comment: Hi Yogendra, is it safe to called multiple requests using the same `AsyncHttpClient client` even though it hasn't return anything on previous request? Or I should create multiple `AsyncHttpClient`? Is it a big overhead to create multiple `AsyncHttpClient`?

Comment: you can call multiple request because all in bg thread