# Access details of a Youtube channel associated with a Google/Google plus account on android

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-plus

I'm in need of accessing the number of subscribers a youtube channel that is associated with the current logged in user has. Online documentation for this seems confusing. I want to prompt user to accept permission requests for viewing their youtube account then I want to retrieve the subscriber count. The latter seems easy but the first part I can't figure out. I'm not sure if I need to retrieve a list of channels from their Google+ profile then get access the details of these channels via youtube data api. or is there a direct way of doing it simply via youtube api where I can prompt a screen to the user so they can select the channel/account they want to go with. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any implementation where you get a Youtube `channel_id` straight from Google+. To prove this I made a REST call using [Google+ Try-it](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get#try-it).
 Checking the response, there was no mention of Youtube channels. This will have to be done using Youtube API.

**"I want to retrieve the subscriber count..is there a direct way of doing it simply via youtube api .."**

Make a 'GET' REST call, you will see the number of subscribers of the channel :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id={CHANNEL_ID}&key={SERVER_API_KEY}
```

(try this in the browser)

To make REST calls in JAVA, try to:

1. Use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), a type-safe HTTP client for Android and Java.
2. Follow steps in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339565/calling-rest-api-from-an-android-app) which uses *Asynchronous Http Client*.