# Should I use AsyncTask or IntentService for making a REST API call?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am learning Android development and creating an app which calls a REST Service on button click which returns a famous quote from a movie. This quote will be shown on the screen (on TextView).

I have added the user permission to the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This is my MainActivity.java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LOGTAG = "info";
    private static final String QUOTES_API = "https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=movies&count=1";
    private static final String MASHAPE_KEY = "this-my-api-key";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button newQuoteBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quotesBtn);

        newQuoteBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String quote = getQuote();
                Log.i(LOGTAG, quote);
                //the quote will be then shown on the text view
            }
        });
    }

    private String getQuote() {
        try {
            URL quotesURL = new URL(QUOTES_API);
            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) quotesURL.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("X-Mashape-Key", MASHAPE_KEY);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            if(conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");

                BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
                StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer(1024);
                String tmp="";
                while((tmp=buffReader.readLine())!=null) {
                    json.append(tmp).append("\n");
                }
                buffReader.close();

                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json.toString());
                Log.i(LOGTAG, data.getString("quote"));
                return data.getString("quote");
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

However when I click the button in the emulator app, nothing happens, it just adds the following message to the logcat

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

From what I am reading, I cannot carry out networking operations on main thread and thats why we have to use AsyncTask. I know that I would need to create a new class which extends AsyncTask but I am still confused about few things:

Q1) Will the new class be an inner class for MainActivity.java or can it be a separate class file as well?

Q2) What will be the params for `class GetQuotesClass extends AsyncTask<?, ?, ?>` do I just send `<void, void, void>` ?

Q3) And how do I call it from my button click? Should I just do `new GetQuotesClass().execute()`?

I also read the following comment in another stack overflow thread

> AsyncTask should not be used for network activity, because it's tied
> to the activity, but not the activity lifecycle. Rotating the device
> with this task is running will cause an exception and crash your app.
> Use an IntentService that drops data in the sqlite database instead

How can I proceed?

Comment: take a look for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339565/calling-rest-api-from-an-android-app

Comment: Found this as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXkjfnhqRGI

Comment: You could use 3rd party libraries like Volley or Retrofit to fetch data through REST API. Both of them work asynchronously on a separate thread and easier to implement

Comment: Yes, that is one way, but I do not want to go into dealing with third party libraries at this moment since I have started learning Android. So I was looking at some in house solutions.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out how to do this, here is the code (minus the API key and other stuff)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LOGTAG = "info";
    private static final String QUOTES_API = "https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=movies&count=1";
    private static final String MASHAPE_KEY = "myapikey";

    TextView quotesTextView, quotesSourceTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button newQuoteBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quotesBtn);
        quotesTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quotesText);
        quotesSourceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quotesSourceText);

        newQuoteBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new GetQuote().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class GetQuote extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private String quote, quoteSource;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL quotesURL = new URL(QUOTES_API);
                HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) quotesURL.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestProperty("X-Mashape-Key", MASHAPE_KEY);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

                if(conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");

                    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
                    StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer(1024);
                    String tmp="";
                    while((tmp=buffReader.readLine())!=null) {
                        json.append(tmp).append("\n");
                    }
                    buffReader.close();

                    JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json.toString());
                    Log.i(LOGTAG, data.getString("quote"));
                    quote = data.getString("quote");
                    quoteSource = data.getString("author");
                } else {
                    quote = "Response code: " + conn.getResponseCode();
                    quoteSource = "Mashape";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                quote = e.getMessage();
                quoteSource = "Exception Class";
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            quotesTextView.setText(quote);
            quotesSourceTextView.setText(quoteSource);
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You decided to use AsyncTask for fetching network requests, despite the known drawbacks of AsyncTask?

Comment: I rewrote my code and I am using Volley now.

Comment: Is Volley serving your needs perfectly, or did you consider using Retrofit as well?

Comment: Volley fits my needs. its a very good service.