# How to fetch data from API and display it in widget?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, widget

I want to create an android app that fetches text from the API and displays this text inside an App widget using Kotlin. How can I implement this?

Comment: The solution is already given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339565/how-do-i-call-rest-api-from-an-android-app

Comment: By "widget", do you mean [app widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/overview)? Also note that asking for off-site resources is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I recommend doing all (or some) of the android codelabs at https://developers.google.com/ before asking that sort of questions. This question is not specific, so we can't properly answer it.

Comment: IMO the question is OK and it's just the kind of answer i've been struggling to find.

Comment: this is legit questions and i'm also looking for a way to get api data to show in app widgets.since documentation is not clear on that

Comment: OP specifically is asking how to display in an app widget, as in a homescreen widget, not a generic view widget such as a textview etc. The question is legit.